# ComboBox not showing certain negative numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

Can't reason why negative numbers -1 to -8 will not show in my `combobox`. I have gone through individual numbers and only the ones mentioned do not work. All other numbers, negative and positive, seem fine. Any clues appreciated.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" md:HintAssist.Hint="Degrees" MinWidth="72" Margin="16 0 0 0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding LongtitudeRange}"
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}">
  <ComboBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Long1" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <domain:NotEmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </ComboBox.Text>
  <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

VM Contructor..

```
LongtitudeRange = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(-179, 359));
```

Property, I've validated that `r` has the correct number.

```
public IList<int> LongtitudeRange { get; }
public double Long1
{
    get
    {
        var l = Conversions.DoubleToDegreeString(SkyServer.Longitude);
        var lsplit = l.Split(':');
        var r = Convert.ToDouble(lsplit[0]);
        return r;
    }
    set
    {
        var l = Conversions.DegreeToDouble(value, Long2, Long3);
        if (Math.Abs(l - SkyServer.Longitude) < 0.00001) return;
        SkyServer.Longitude = l;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I call this from another method to initiate the update `OnPropertyChanged($"Long1");`

Comment: Why do you bind the ComboBox's Text property? Don't you just want to select an integer longitude value from the dropdown list? And shouldn't there be 360 values instead of 359? Also note the typo in `LongtitudeRange`

Comment: And instead of parsing a deg/min/sec string you should better directly get the values from `SkyServer.Longitude` by floating point arithmetics.

Comment: Changing to Index or Value gives the same result.  360 is invalid as 179 59 59 is the max. Thanks for the typo!

Comment: Isn't it -179:59:59 to +180:00:00? You would have to fix min and sec to zero for 180 degress, but it should somehow be settable.

Comment: -179 59 59.999 to 0 0 0.001 works and doesn't need the validation of someone typing in 180 0 1

Comment: So back to my initial question, why do you bind the ComboBox's Text property, when `SelectedItem` would give you the appropriate integer longitude degree value? And does the dropdown have empty lines instead of numbers -1 to -8 or are they just missing? It's hard to reproduce that.

Comment: Switching to SelectedItem worked but I'm more confused over why the others didn't.  Care to explain in an answer?

Comment: It's certainly the way your Long1 property getter works. You should debug it and, as said, consider to implement it without string conversions.

Comment: I did switch out the strings for ints but the return getter is still sending the same value in the binding as it was.  As Text it couldn't find specific values in the itemsource but as seletedItem it worked, too strange for me.  Thanks for the help!